# How to get the name of input field with PHP

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm trying to create a function. which will check if the field is empty or not. If the input is empty it'll push an error for that input in the error array.

```
$errors = ["name" => "Name is required"];
```

like so

How can I do this?

```
function checkRequiredFields($fields = [], $errors = [])
{
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (is_blank($field)) {
      $errors[$field] = "$field is required";
    }
  }
}
```

btw here's how my `is_blank` function looks:

```
function is_blank($value)
{
  return !isset($value) || trim($value) === '';
}
```

Comment: So you're looking for an implementation of is_blank()?

Comment: (My opinion ahead: Doing validation this way is kind of clumsy to work with, since it's the same check for all fields. If you want other checks for some of the fields you'll get a bunch of less than readable if clauses, or similar.)

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the field has been submitted and doesn't hold the empty string:

```
<?php

function check_required_fields($fields, &$errors) {
    foreach($fields as $fieldname) {
        if(isset($_POST[$fieldname]) && $_POST[$fieldname] === '') {
            $errors[$fieldname][] = "'$fieldname' is required.";
        }
    }
}
check_required_fields(['email'], $errors);
?>
<form method='POST'>
    <input type='text'  name='name'>
    <input type='email' name='email'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the values of the input fields with

`$field = $_GET["field"]; // or $_POST["field"];` depending of your form.

But you need to sanitize properly your input values for security reasons.

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.filter-input.php

The empty() function is also what you're looking for.

```
 if (empty($field)) {
  $errors[$field] = "$field is required";
}
```

Checkout the documentation : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php

Take a look at the isset() function also.

Comment: Doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: I am not using `empty()` because it returns true if the value is 0.